# Assets within public directory give 404 errors in Next.js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, favicon, head

I have been trying to get the favicon for my site (uses next.js) to show up. After going through countless Stack Overflow posts and tutorials, I am starting to get frustrated.
My project's structure, and specifically the public directory looks like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── components
├── next.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── pages
├── public
│   ├── android-chrome-192x192.png
│   ├── android-chrome-512x512.png
│   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   ├── css
│   ├── favicon-16x16.png
│   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── mstile-150x150.png
│   ├── safari-pinned-tab.svg
│   └── site.webmanifest
└── utils
```

The beginning of my app.js file looks like this:

```
export default function Layout({ children, page }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5" />
        .....
      </Head>
```

After following [this](https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-add-custom-dynamic-favicons-in-react-next-js/) tutorial, I am left with console errors that read: `GET http://localhost:3000/favicon-32x32.png 404 (Not Found)`. I also tried to load the favicons through a site.webmanifest file linked in the Head with `<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" crossorigin="use-credentials">` but this tag also left a `404 (Not Found)` error in the console.

I have verified that the favicon png's are the correct size, 16x16 & 32x32. It seems that any assets living in my public directory that I am trying to link to in the `<Head>` are not being found.

Is there anything else that I can try to get these favicons showing up?

Edit: Here are the contents of my `next.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/my-path',

  webpack: (config) => {
    return config
  },

  env: {
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    BACKEND_API_URL: ...
    CONSENT_COOKIE_NAME: ...
  },
}
```

Comment: I guess you have to allow something in next-config.js

Comment: @RanuVijay I have a custom webpack config, but what should be added in here to link the favicon properly?

Comment: Have you tried a clean build, i.e., deleting the `.next` directory before rerunning?

Comment: @MarkG I just tried this and had no luck with it. Favicons are still showing as not found.

Comment: The issue is likely in your custom webpack config, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @FINDarkside I added the contents of my next.config.js file to the original post. I haven't been able to find any examples online of people editing this file to support rendering static assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've set your `basePath` to `/my-path` in your `next.config.js`, you'll need to include that in your other path references as well, e.g.:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/my-path/favicon-32x32.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
```

I think favicon should be in ICO format. The favicon is supposed to be a set of 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48. If you use online favicon generator, they set the size automatically

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I have already tried including the favicon.ico in the <Head> and that left me with another `404 (Not Found)` error in the console.

Comment: make sure file is in correct path.

Comment: I have verified that it is correct, but 404 errors persist

Comment: can you change the file name: favicon-32x32. it might not be a valid name. or just  find a .ico image and try that. it should work

Comment: One of my first attempts at debugging was to just use the favicon.ico that we have and just link that in the head, but this didn't work. @RanuVijay suggested that I might have to allow assets to be rendered. But I am not sure what this would look like.